# Would using a side menu in my portfolio page be a design faux pas?

Tags: website-design, portfolio

I'm a full-stack developer, creating a portfolio page with node and react. I'm using a side menu that has some pretty cool features, and I think it looks great. I want the page itself to have a minimalist look to it, which is why I chose the side menu.

However, I was wondering if using a side menu would be tedious, and in this case not very functional? And whether an employer may frown upon it. I included some images (site is far from complete, but the menu is finished) to help with an opinion.

Any input greatly appreciated!

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think this is entirely too opinion based. It's along the same lines as asking if using "blue" would be off putting for an employer --- it might be to some, but how would anyone know.

Comment: @Scott I appreciate the comment! However, I know that many design concepts are frowned upon in certain instances. Me not being a "design" guy per se, I was hoping for some constructive input.

Comment: Side menus are not a horrible thing, if they suit a design. There's no right or wrong answer as to hen to use them or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need to worry about it. Your design looks clean and well thought out. As someone who has looked at a lot of portfolios and interviewed programmers and designers, I have seen many less appealing sites. This design should not exclude you from getting an interview.